# Applied example of the weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider a sequence of random variables $X_{n}$ such as $P({X_{n}} = a) = 0$ for $ \forall a, a \ne 0, a\ne 1 $.
Is it possible to define a common distribution but have $$X_{n} \ne X_{p}, \forall (n,p), n \ne p$$

My understanding is that if two random variables are equal they are not independent so to use the law of large numbers you must have them different from one each other.

If this is the case could we apply the law of weak numbers to this sequence ?

Comment: Are you prepared to consider continuous distributions where $P(X=x)=0\, \forall x$?

Comment: I'd rather not, or could you explain why it is not possible with the condition I gave. I understand it is possible with continuous ones though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $U \sim Unif([0,1])$ and define Bernoulli random variables for each $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ by
\begin{align}
X_n &= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & \mbox{ if $U \in \left[\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2n}+1/3\right]$} \\ 
0 & \mbox{ else} 
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
The random variables $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are distinct but they have the same distribution because $P[X_n =1] =1/3$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

And $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ does not converge to $1/3$ in probability.

---

Aside: If by $X_n \neq X_p$ you mean that $X_n(\omega) \neq X_p(\omega)$ for all $n\neq p$ and all $\omega \in S$, then note that if $P[X_n=0]=\theta>0$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, then the events $$\{X_1=0\}, \{X_2=0\}, ..., \{X_k=0\}$$ cannot be disjoint if $k$ satisfies $k>1/\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. What  is the sample space for this random variable $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i $  given some  $ n $ and for the infinite series ?

Comment: You can say the sample space is $S=[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure and $U(\omega)=\omega$ for the uniform random variable.  And the $X_n(\omega)$ variables are functions of $U(\omega)$.